JWT is not valid when cheking on jwt.io
I am attempting to upgrade the project from Next.js 12.5 to Next.js 13.5.6 and NextAuth 3 to NextAuth 4. However, I am encountering an issue while encrypting the token. _jose.encryptJWT is skipping the inclusion of the payload in the generated token.
Next-auth 3 :
 jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET, { algorithm: 'HS256', expiresIn: '1 day' });
Next-auth 4:

I commented out and configured the NEXT_AUTH_SECRET and JWT_TOKEN in my environment variables, as mentioned in NextAuth 4, since we don't need to sign the token explicitly. Perhaps my understanding is incorrect. Otherwise, the code remains the same. The same code is working with Next-Auth3 version without any issues.I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and still could not determine what else needs to be provided to include the payload in the generated token. Please let me know if you need more information.
async jwt({token, user}) {
  
            token.name = "xyz2024"
            token.email="xyz2024@xyz.com";
            if(user) 
            {
                if(user.statusMessage) {
                    token.username = user.statusMessage?.username;
                    token.name = user.statusMessage?.username;
                  }
                if(user.databaseUser) {
                        if(user.databaseUser.personIdentifier)
                        {   
                            token.username = user.databaseUser.personIdentifier
                            token.sub = user.databaseUser.personIdentifier
                            token.databaseUser = user.databaseUser
                            token.email = user.databaseUser.email ?? "szd2013@gmail.com"
                            token.picture ='self' 
                        }
                }
             
                if(user.userRoles)
                    token.userRoles = user.userRoles;
               // token.alg = 'HS256';*/
                // Sign the JWT token with the payload using your custom secret
               /* const secret = process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET; // Replace with your own secret
                token = jwt.sign(token, secret, {
                expiresIn: '1 day', // Optionally set the token expiration
                });*/

               
          // } 
          
         
            // Return null if neither encoding nor decoding logic applies
           return token;
            
        },   

async jwt({token, user}) {
  
             token.name = "xyz2024"
            token.email="xyz2024@xyz.com";
            if(user) 
            {
                if(user.statusMessage) {
                    token.username = user.statusMessage?.username;
                    token.name = user.statusMessage?.username;
                  }
                if(user.databaseUser) {
                        if(user.databaseUser.personIdentifier)
                        {   
                            token.username = user.databaseUser.personIdentifier
                            token.sub = user.databaseUser.personIdentifier
                            token.databaseUser = user.databaseUser
                            token.email = user.databaseUser.email ?? "szd2013@gmail.com"
                            token.picture ='self' 
                        }
                }
             
                if(user.userRoles)
                    token.userRoles = user.userRoles;
               // token.alg = 'HS256';*/
                // Sign the JWT token with the payload using your custom secret
               /* const secret = process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET; // Replace with your own secret
                token = jwt.sign(token, secret, {
                expiresIn: '1 day', // Optionally set the token expiration
                });*/

               
          // } 
          
         
            // Return null if neither encoding nor decoding logic applies
           return token;
            
        }, 


Can anyone help me with this?
